# Java Array Loop outofbound

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea

I am at the beginner Java level, learning the basics of the array loop, coding in Intellij.
I have been following online tutorials from various places and am stuck at this one: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/arrays_and_loops.html

Using the same code as:

```
package com.java.ArraysA;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] lottery_numbers = new int[49];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lottery_numbers.length; i++); {
        lottery_numbers[i] = i + 1;
        System.out.println(lottery_numbers[i] );
    }
}
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49
at com.java.ArraysA.Main.main(Main.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Any help with where the code is wrong would be much appreciated.

This is the only place I have come unstuck so far and can't seem to find what the problem is even though it may be an obvious one, so apologies in advance if that is the case.

Answer (score 7):

You are closing your loop prematurely:

```
for (i = 0; i < lottery_numbers.length; i++);
                                            ^ remove this ;
```

Currently you have an empty loop (i.e. without a body) that only increments `i` until it reaches `lottery_numbers.length` (i.e. 49).

Then the `{}` block that follows the loop is executed once.

When that block is executed, `lottery_numbers[49]` throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate the quick help. No wonder it wouldn't work with the extra wrongly placed ';'. Everything else made sense to me and was driving me 'loopy'. All in working order now.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are zero based. So an array of length 49 (which is what you are creating with `new int[49]` will have indexes between 0 and 48. Index 49 does not exist.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: This isn't an answer at all !!!

Comment: What are you people talking about? How does it not answer the question? Did I have to go so far as to say that the following line ```for (i = 0; i < lottery_numbers.length; i++); {``` should read length - 1 for you to be satisfied?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. now I see the semi-colon that Eran was talking about. Oops.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help and yes the problem was indeed the ';'.        The lottery_numbers[i] = i + 1 coding ensured the last loop value to be 48 + 1 = 49 if that helps you too...